# Opencart Issue Config Step 3 - "Error: Could not connect to the database please make..."

Tags: php, mysql, database, opencart, shopping-cart

IF someone is familiar with Opencart please help. I am in the stages of experimenting with shopping carts and I have very little knowledge MySQL.

**Issue**

*"Error: Could not connect to the database please make sure the database server, username and password is correct!"*

I have been through Cpanel and created a Database (DB) to fill in the relevant fields. These are the fields that I have filled:

> (drop down) MySQLi - MySQL (What is the difference?)
>
> (Input Field) Database Host : localhost (where does this need to point to?)
>
> (Input) Username and then password : I have entered a password without special characters, but I     can't remove the underscore from the user name. These were made in Cpanel.
>
> Database Name : I have entered the database name here but cant remove "dsdsdsd_databasename"
>
> Database Prefix : oc_ I have left this as is... What is this prefix?

And the I have entered the username admin and password - any pointers?

Comment: Error message clearly states: `please make sure the database server, username and password is correct`. Check if username and password do not contain any other characters than letters and numbers (OpenCart requires so) and then check IP address or URL of your database server. Use `localhost` only when web server and database server work on the same machine.

Comment: Thank you. Localhost was the relevant field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All appears to be working with the config!  I can see the login. Although if anyone could answer my bullet points above that would be appreciated.

In the end I went into the Cpanel, scrolled down to '**MySQL wizard**' and followed the steps. I believe my names and passwords were correct from before as typed these a few times. The difference with using the wizard in Cpanel was that it allowed an option at the end that allowed '**all privileges**' - ticked the box and before long I could see the admin panel.

Hope this helps.